# Python picking 'python2.7' instead of 'python' for USER_SITE

Tags: python

```
> python2.7 -m site
sys.path = [
    <PATHS>
]
USER_BASE: '/mounted/on/remote/dir/sshfs/basedir' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/mounted/on/remote/dir/sshfs/basedir/lib/python/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

The reason it shows as 'doesn't exist' because what actually exists is `/mounted/on/remote/dir/sshfs/basedir/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Is there an easy way to force my local python interpreter to look at `python2.7` instead of `python` in `USER_SITE`? It doesn't make a difference if I invoke `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python2.7`.